# Regex with 2 semi colons in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have data like this

```
Giftsbirth;;Basket7;CC
Giftswedding;;Cake4;COD
```

I am trying to find a regex that will only select the second data (Basket7, Cake4).

From past help I tried something like

```
^(\w+ [^\v;;]+;;[^\v;]+)?.*
```

But I know that is not right

Please assist with the regex if you can

Comment: Are you sure you have to use `\v`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a positive lookbehind `(?<=` to assert what is before is `;;` and a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert that what follows is `;`

Use a negative [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^;]+` to match not a `;` to match your values.

[`(?<=;;)[^;]+(?=;)`](https://regex101.com/r/mUJjzB/1)

Comment: @JaneLaville See my answer with two solutions that work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?:.*;)?([^;\n\r]+);[^;\n\r]+$
```

Or,

```
.*?;;([^;\r\n]+)(?:;.*)?
```

and replace with `$1`.

**Details**

- `(?:.*;)?` - an optional substring having 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the `;`
- `([^;\n\r]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than CR, LF and `;`
- `;` - a semi-colon
- `[^;\n\r]+` -  any one or more chars other than CR, LF and `;`
- `$` - end of line.

The second regex matches

- `.*?;;` - any 0+ chars as few as possible up to (and including) the first `;;`
- `([^;\r\n]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than CR, LF and `;`
- `(?:;.*)?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of a `;` and then any 0+ chars up to the end of line

The `$1` in the replacement is the value you need to keep.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify more precisely what "the second data (Basket7, Cake4)" means. This looks like CSV data with the `;` set as separator, but that would place Basket7 and Cake4 in the *third column*, since the second column is empty. In order to write a regex that solves this problem *in the general case*, you need to take into account the full domain of possible lines, and you've only given two examples and let everyone guess what the underlying format and total possible variations might be.

For example, is it always reasonable to assume that that which you're looking for is always preceded by `;;` and ends with a `;`, and that `;;` never occurs in other places than immediately before that which you're looking for? In that case, `(?<=;;)([^;]*)` captures this. But what if you encounter one of the following lines?

```
Giftsbirth;;;CC             # Here, the thing matched is empty
Giftsbirth;1600;Basket7;CC  # Here, the second column isn't empty
;;Basket7;CC                # Here, the first column is empty
;;;CC                       # Here, all but the last column are empty
;;;                         # Here, all columns are empty
```

You may experience that various suggestions will give you "the right text", but if you test this on a limited subset that does not account for all variations that can reasonably be expected in the input, you will inevitably have to revise your regex.

Assuming this is a CSV *where the fields don't contain literal `;`s*, and that you don't know anything about the length of any of the fields (and consequently that the second column isn't always empty), but that there are at least three columns, you could consider the regex:

```
^[^;]*;[^;]*;([^;]*)
```

(See demo at https://regex101.com/r/vhPNEj/1)

---

These assumptions may not be correct, but my ability to guess are much worse than yours, since you're sitting with a larger sample size of data. In order to succeed at automating your tasks, it is critical that you learn to modify code to fit your assumptions.

For example, you may want to disregard the cases where the third column is empty:

```
^[^;]*;[^;]*;([^;]+)
```

Here the difference is `[^;]*` changed into `[^;]+`.

Or you may want to take into account that the first column could contain semicolons when they are wrapped in double quotes, e.g. like `"Giftsbirth; Holiday";;Basket7;CC`:

```
^(?:[^;"]*|"[^"]*");[^;]*;([^;]*)
```

Here the difference is `[^;]*` changed into `(?:[^;"]*|"[^"]*")` being *either* `[^;"]*` (being all but `;` and `"`) *or* `"[^"]*"` (being `"` followed by anything but `"`, which includes `;`, followed by `"`).